# Why do buses not have seat belts if cars have to have them?

Tags: car, safety, security

This has always struck me as odd. People just board this huge thing that moves around and never even question why there are no seat belts.

But a normal car (even a larger bus-like one) *has* to have seatbelts by law, and any passengers are required (also by law?) to wear them whenever it's moving.

What exactly is the difference? What makes a large bus safer than a car/small bus that you don't need any seat belts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question (interesting though it may be) is off-topic here. It is not about motor vehicle maintenance and repair, but is instead about economics and politics.

Comment: All buses where I come from do have seat belts and it is mandatory to wear them.

Comment: There is some amount of science behind so as to why buses don't have seatbelts, in addition to economics and politics. While i would agree that it's more of an engineering or physics aspect than a motor vehicle related question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons that i could think of

1. Most buses usually don't have a transmission to be driven at high speeds nor does the law allow you to. In the event of an accident since buses tend to be travelling at low speed the chances of injury from accident is lower as compared to cars.
2. In the event of accident , particularly vehicle to vehicle collisions the chances are higher for buses to collide with a smaller vehicle. In such cases a heavy vehicle such as a bus would suffer less change in velocity during collision compared to a car (cars have higher probability of colliding with a larger vehicle in which case it will suffer a vary large change in velocity during collision). In simple terms there is a higher chance for passengers in cars to suffer a higher rate of change in velocity during collision which could send them flying compared to passengers in bus.
3. The gap between two adjacent seat (row wise) is generally kept very small mainly for spatial economy. But it has a plus point. A close set of seat means there isn't enough time for passengers to accelerate to a higher velocity ,in the event of collision. This is because the seat ahead of you will make sure you bump onto it before attaining a high velocity. Thus reducing passenger's impact.
4. Other non-technical reasons would be the cost, cost to benefit ratio, convenience. In public transports this isn't often viable because most people aren't gonna bother spending time on buckling and unbuckling seat belts especially the small distance travellers.

While i don't have much idea on how public transport bus systems are in western countries, in countries like india there isn't any strict limit on number of passengers you can have at a time (legally there is but no one follows it). So they pretty much stuff in as many people as they can. And since most buses generally travel over short distances and hence there will be large number of people changing the seat after every bus stop, in which case seatbelts even if it is present would be of no consequence.

Disclaimer: using a seatbelt is always beneficial from a safety point of view (if it is there).

Comment: Are any road regulations followed in India? Do they even exist?

Comment: Ha ha there are a lot of regulations but the people following it are very less. And the authority doesn't bother enforcing them either.  Although speed limits are now being a thing.

Answer (score 0):

They do have seat belts and it is your choice or common sense to wear them.

However, it may be that some countries are using old busses which do not have seat belts fitted. Some of these may be capable of being retro fitted.

That also depends on the legislation, if any, which may or may not require busses already in use or manufactured prior to a certain date to be so equipped.

Answer (score -2):

The absence of seat belts on trains and buses can seem confounding, but the reasoning spans financial concerns, accessibility and comfort, and even, perhaps paradoxically, safety considerations. In late 2016, buses that provide service between cities and tour buses must be equipped with lap-and-shoulder seat belts, according to a federal rule laid out in 2013. But that rule does not apply to school buses or city buses. The National Highway Traffic Safety Administration said the measures are meant to bring down the annual number of deaths and injuries reported in bus crashes each year — 21 and 8,000, respectively.
In NYC, neither trains nor buses have seat belts. Each state sets guidelines on seat/shoulder belts, usually following federal guidelines. In general, metropolitan bus drivers are better trained since they must avoid every person intent on crossing against signage, dodging between parked vehicles, oblivious texters looking down while crossing a street, and slowed down by heavy traffic. This combination has a tendency to reduce speeds to below 20 mph. The most powerful brakes capable of stopping a 20k-33k lb bus weighting up to 44k lbs loaded with passengers rarely makes emergency braking causing passengers to slide off their seats or standing passengers to fall down. All due mainly to a safety culture of safe bus drivers. Taking all this into account, seat belts aren't required for NYC public bus transportation.